# PHP скачивание изображения в папку

Tags: php, массивы

Всем привет!

У меня в массиве лежит список ссылок на изображения) как с помощью PHP можно 
скачать изображения по этим ссылкам в заданную папку? allow_url_fopen включен!
Пробовал что то такое...

```
    $c = count($imgs);
    foreach($imgs as $l){
    for($i =0;$i < $c; $i++){
    file_put_contents("/var/www/html/img/$i" .'.jpg',file_get_contents($l));
    }
```

Заранее спасибо)

Comment: мы тут телепаты думаете? Какая ошибка при выполнении сего кода? Директория на запись не доступна, или тайм лимит на выполнение скрипта не проходит? Уберите двойной цикл на скачивание, у вас тут не `N`-файлов, в `N^2` скачивается перезаписывая друг друга

Comment: @teran Спасибо за замечание) ошыбок не выводит, права на папку 777

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел ответ!
 Создаем функцию для обрезания пути файла.
         function split_path($full_path) {

```
     $path_parts = pathinfo($full_path);  // Возвращает информацию о пути к файлу
     return $path_parts['basename'];  // получаем только имя файла
     }  

   foreach($imgs as $l){     // перебираем ссылки на фото
   $pic=file_get_contents($l);   //получаем содержимое
   $a = split_path($l);     // обрезаем путь и получаем только 
   $h = fopen("/var/www/html/parser/img/$a", "a+"); //указываем путь к папке на запись

   fwrite($h, $pic); // записываем
   fclose($h);      // закрываем дескриптор
   }
```